# difference between onTouch and onClick listener and use of multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to make some application in android (some kind of calculator app). In the app, on pressing the buttons a lot of conditions get checked using if-else. I am using onClickListener with the buttons, and so they are taking a slightly longer time to respond. So should I use multithreading to separate the logic from the main thread or rather use an onTouchListener with the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the click event, keep using *onClick*, *onTouch* is used for tracking gestures.
2. It's not a good practice to do any logic operation inside the *Main Thread*. Leave it just for user interaction. You should consider use threading to avoid *ANR* (Application not responding). A good start is *AsyncTask*, that has it own method to do logic in a separete thread and update the *UI* on the *Main Thread*.

Please follow this link to get help with *AsyncTask*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18827536/4973904

Hope that this could help you!

Answer (score 0):

you should not do too much work on Main thread.The problem is not **if else** statements because conditional statements execute very fast but the logic you have written inside the if else blocks .may be your logic taking to much time to execute.

Solution:

```
     if you want to perform extensive task , you should use some background thread or an alternative of this like   Async task or Loaders.
```